# spring security pre authenticated user login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I need to login a user manually into a application secured by spring security.
My scenario is

1. user logs into application 1.
2. A link to my spring application will be available.
3. when user clicks the link, Application 1 will post encrypted data to an unsecured url in my spring app.
4. Now my controller will receive the encrypted data and  call a web service
       in application 1, encrypted data will be passed in the web service and I get a response with the user name.
5. once I get the user name. I do not want to re authenticate. I just want to set the user principal / authentication object and load the dashboard.

Step 1 to 4 is working.

In my unsecured controller (where I get the encrypted data )
I  have the following lines , but this is again invoking my authentication manager, and I do not want to authenticate again in this scenario. I just want the session to be created and user principal to be set.

```
String username = application1.webservice(encoded data);
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
     return "redirect:/app";
```

Note : I do have form based LDAP authentication working (this will be used if the user directly logs into my app)
I am using spring security 3.2  / Java Config

Answer (score 0):

The `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is responsible for setting up a `SecurityContext` in the `SecurityContextHolder` at the beginning of a web request. And any changes to the `SecurityContext` during request processing will be copied to the `HttpSession` when the web request ends.

So when you're updating the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContext`, this filter will update the `HttpSession` at the end of the authentication request.

Can you confirm the `JSESSIONID` being sent back on the authentication response is the same being passed on all subsequent requests?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.  I added a custom authentication provided and solved.